# How can I diagnose what is using my 3g connection in small packets

Tags: data-connection, mobile-data, data-monitoring

My GSM carrier rounds all used data up to 100KB. Which means that if some app is sending/receiving 500 bytes, I get charged for 100KB.

Lately I observed that I go through several hundred megabytes per day.

Data usage in phone shows that I used ~ 400MB, while carrier charged me for over 2GB of data.

In detailed billing I see literally thousands of short connections (multiple per minute, 24 hours a day), each using 100KB - which means that actual data transfer is much lower.

Carrier helpdesk said that they can't tell me what I'm using the data for. Phone shows real data transfer, which in my case is useless.

What can I do to find out what application/process is sending lots of small packets of data (or receives)?

If it helps with anything, I'm using Motorola Moto G2 (only 1 SIM has data transfer enabled), and it's running Android 5.0.2.

While debugging the problem, I disabled Google Backup Services from using 3G (only works over Wifi now), and an hour ago I disabled it altogether. But given that it was disabled over 3G, I don't think it's the culprit.

Comment: Many apps transfer small amounts of data to either ask for new messages or send a heartbeat to the server so it knows that your device is able to receive messages. Some apps may allow you to disable such features, so try that. Apart from that if were you, I would change the carrier because rounding up to 100kb is just stupid.

Comment: Do you not have a data monitor under `Settings -> Wireless` or similar?

Comment: @GiantTree I know all this, the problem is how to find what app is causing the situation now.

Comment: @MatthewRead - of course I have it - I mentioned "data usage". The problem is that it doesn't show me number of connections just data transferred. Which (in my, very special case) is the wrong thing.

Comment: I recommend looking into `Background Data` in `Settings -> Data Usage -> Menu item "Restrict background data"` or similar. That way apps can only issue a remote connection, if they are running in the foreground (I'm sure this means on screen). So no app can load data in background, but many apps will have problems (especially messaging apps).

Comment: If you are in a western nation then the 100KiB rounding may be illegal. The EU has specific caps on rounding, i.e. call billing used to be rounded to the whole minute, now the law limits the carriers to billing in 6-second intervals. There are similar caps on data billing rounding.

Comment: @GiantTree: I know about this. But I don't know which app to restrict, so it's kinda pointless.

Comment: @dotancohen and how does it help me? Sure, I "can" sue the telecom. and after months or years, I will win (????). It has *nothing* to do with my problem now.

Comment: @aguy Restricting `Background Data` does not need you to specify an app; it restricts it for *all* apps at once.

Comment: @GiantTree: Will try. But I'm **much** more interested in diagnosing which app is causing the problem than blocking all the apps. After all, I could disable data transfer over 3G altogether, but that's not a solution I'm really looking for :(

Answer (score 0):

To diagnose the issue you could try a third-party network monitoring tool - [Network Connections](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.antispycell.connmonitor&hl=en)

> Powerful tool that displays and monitors (tracks) all inbound and
>   outbound connection from and to your Android device.

Other features bundles in the app:

> - Monitors all internet connections from and to your Android device
> - Displays notification when hidden apps are connecting to remote servers
> - Displays detailed IP information for each connection - IP address, reverse resolving (PTR), AS number, Abuse RBL data, administrative
>     information, etc.
> - Gets detailed info about each app that connects to remote servers and network connections used by it - permissions granted to each
>     captured package and all IP addresses used by it.

[image]